# Creating MS SQL Server Logins

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have SQL server 2008 local installation and my xyzdomain/user has the access to the SQL server . Now my machine is moved to abcdomain and i am not able to access the Database server because the only user allowed on the DB is of different domain and my machine having the SQL server is now in different domain .
PS: OS is Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you log on with the SA account ?
If you don't know the password you can reset it:
[link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx)

This procedure cover how to add domain accounts to sql server. The key is to start SQL in single use mode to send sql statement as explained in the post:
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'xyzdomain\Myadminaccount', 'sysadmin';

Then you can restart SQL server in normal mode, connect through SQL Management Studio and add all needed accounts

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here:

Connect to the SQL machine with a local admin account and assign your new domain account to the SQL server.

If your xyzdomain/user account is an admin for SQL, switch your machine back to the xyzdomain temporarily so that you can assign your new domain account to the SQL server.

Have someone else with administrative rights to the SQL server assign you access.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to connect with the local Administrator account. It should have administrative permissions on that SQL Server.

Do you have a trust relationship between the xyzdomain and abcdomain?

Comment: no the domains dont have a trust relation ship .
My account itself is the admin and i tried logging with local admin account too , it dosen't allows to log in

Comment: That is strange. Under which account do SQL server services run?   
Change them to run under an account from the new domain or a local account.   
Check also that Windows firewall does not prevent you from accessing that SQL Server.   
Can you move the computer back to the old domain, change security settings and than move it to the new domain again?